# Simplex method and convex sets

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I know that the simplex method is a well known method for finding optimal values in linear programming.
I am trying to understand how it works. 
If I have understood, you move alongside the edges of the polytope until you reach a vertex, which is locally optimum. And now it is my question:

Because the polytope is a convex set, then does it follows that the local optimum is also a global optimum? If the polytope wouldn't be a convex set, then the local optimum can be different from the global optimum?

Answer (score 2):

You need both the fact that the polytope is a convex set and the fact the function that you are maximizing is linear and therefore convex. If either the function or the set are not convex, then a local optimum is not necessarily a global one